# Understanding Divide and Conquer method

Tags: data-structures

I cant seem to understand my prof. Notes

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + c
     = T(n/2^2) + c
     = T(n/2^3) + c
     ...
     = T(n/2^k) + kc

 recursion bottoms out when n/2^k < 1, ie when k > lg n
```

which is different from what I got

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + c
      = T((n/2+c)/2) + c
      = T(n/2^2) + c/2 + c
      =...
```

another

```
 T(n)= 5T(n/3) + n^2
     = 5^2T(n/3^2) + 5(n/3)^2 + n^2
     =... 

 is what he got, but I got was
     =5^2T(n/3^2) + 5(n^2/3) + n^2
     =...                  ^where did he get the square from? I dont seem to get it
```

what am i doing wrong math wise?

Answer (score 0):

To me it just looks like he's saying you cut the problem in halves, forths, eights, etc.  Those are your powers of two.

Eventually you hit a point where you can't cut the problem into any more pieces (there are no more n to divide).

He's not doing math, he's just describing the overall process of repeatedly dividing a problem into 2 pieces.

Comment: So im assuming that would apply to the second method as well?

Comment: I agree the math notation does not look like standard math. In the second case it makes more sense if you remove the T() symbol.  The square is coming from n^2.  I agree it's puzzling.  :)